# how to stream data out of a cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, streaming, spark-streaming, spring-xd

I would like to stream data from a cassandra table which is updated in real time. Yes, it is a database but is there a way to do that? If so, keeping an offset or what CQL queries can I use ?

Comment: Does anyone have some idea on how spark-cassandra-connector can be used in this ? does it take of care of offset on its own and does it stream data in near real time  ?

Answer (score 7):

Short answer is no.

Long answer is with a lot of difficulty and smart clustering keys you can maybe do that. Basically if you insert data with a clustering key that always increases you can always just scan for clustering keys in a recent time gap. This will of course miss out-of-order inserts outside of your window. This may or may not be good enough for your use case.

Best answer in the future is Change Data Capture: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8844

Comment: Maybe also triggers?

Comment: Does anyone have some idea on how spark-cassandra-connector can be used in this ? does it take of care of offset on its own and does it stream data in near real time ?

Comment: No, and no. It does neither of these things, as I said you would have to develop some custom code for your own tables (or design custom triggers and receivers)

Comment: If you really need a streaming approach most find it easiest to insert into a queue and the using something like Spark Streaming to analyze data.

Comment: @RussS so future is already here! That ticket was resolved few months ago. Then do you have any ideas how to use it with Spark?

Comment: Yep, write a Spark Streaming Dstream which uses CDC as it's source

Comment: see @alex channelmeter's answer, I think it works fine

Comment: @cholosrus that answer would be for paging a very long request, it would not Stream changes from C* which I believe was the intention.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you were asking specifically about streaming data out of Cassandra, but I would like to suggest that a technology like [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org) sounds like a much better fit for what you're trying to do. It is used by a [number of other large companies](https://kafka.apache.org/powered-by) and has fantastic real-time performance.

There is a seminal blog post by Jay Kreps called [The Log: What every software engineer should know about real-time data's unifying abstraction](https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying) that does a great job of explaining Kafka's purpose and design. A key quote from the blog post summarizes Kafka's role:

> Take all the organization's data and put it into a central log for real-time subscription.

Answer (score 0):

To stream the data from Cassandra, you want to use the PageSize option like so:

```
iter := cass.Query(`SELECT * FROM cmuser.users;`).PageSize(100).Iter()
```

the above is an example with Golang. The description for PageSize is:

> PageSize will tell the iterator to fetch the result in pages of
>   size n. 
>   This is useful for iterating over large result sets, but
>   setting the 
>   page size too low might decrease the performance. This
>   feature is only available in Cassandra 2 and onwards.

Comment: don't do this if you have significant amounts of data in the tables...

Comment: why? The pagesize should help prevent too much data being read into the golang process

Comment: Because is need to go to different nodes, as there is no load balancing, etc. this creates a load on coordinator... better solution is to make scan by token ranges, and route them explicitly to replicas

Comment: then please add an answer using token ranges, and link to that here

Comment: the answer about `select * from table` is really doesn't answer the original question - author wants to have only changes since last scan. The best answer is from @RussS... If you interested in token range scan - I have a separate answer about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104383/performance-of-token-range-based-queries-on-partition-keys/54108700#54108700