# How do you UPDATE a Cassandra column without directly knowing the primary key?

Tags: cassandra

Given a scenario where you have a `User` table, with `id` as PRIMARY KEY.
You have a column called `email`, and a column called `name`.

You want to `UPDATE` `User.name` based on `User.email`

I realized that the `UPDATE` command requires you to pass in a PRIMARY KEY. Does this mean I can't use a pure `CQL` migration, and would need to first query for the `User.id` primary key before I can `UPDATE`?

In this case, I DO know the PRIMARY KEY because the UUIDs are the same for `dev` and `prod`, but it feels dirty.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're correct - you need to know primary key of the record to perform an update on the data, or deletion of specific record. There are several options here, depending of your data model:

1. Perform full scan of the table using effective token range scan (Look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104383/performance-of-token-range-based-queries-on-partition-keys/54108700#54108700) for more details);
2. If this is required very often, you can create a materialized view, with `User.email` as partition key, and fetch all message IDs that you can update (but you'll need to do this from your application, there is no nested query support in CQL). But also be aware that materialized views are "experimental" feature in Cassandra, and may not work all the time (it's more stable in DataStax Enterprise). Also, if you have some users with hundreds of thousands of emails, this may create big partitions.
3. Do like 2nd item with your code, by using an additional table

Comment: I think it's worth noting that (2) can also be implemented, without using experimental features, by simply writing the needed data to a different table mapping `email` to `id`.

Comment: Yes - but it’s additional logic in code. But I’ve updated answer  - thank you

Comment: This answer is correct (and, by the way, a fourth possibility could be to use a secondary index instead of a materialized view), but there's something you note: "id" is your key so it is unique (each record has a unique id). But user.email may not be unique: If you search for a specific user.email, you may get 2 (or 20,000) different records with this same email. Do you want to change all these users' names to the same thing? Or something else?

Comment: that's requires more "business" knowledge :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54408102/3408454) covers your question -- "how can I find a value in a PK column working backwards from a non-PK column's value?".

However, I think it's worth noting that asking this question indicates you should reconsider your data model. A rule of thumb in C* data model design is that you begin by considering the queries you need, and you've missed the `UPDATE` query use case. You can probably make things work without changing your model for now, but if you find you need to make other queries you're unprepared for, you'll run into operational issues with lots of indexes and/or MVs.

More generally, search around for articles and other resources about Cassandra data modeling. It sounds like you're basically using C* for a relational use case so you'll want to look into that.